# Why do I have SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jestjs

I am trying to run [mockingoose](https://github.com/alonronin/mockingoose) example

```
> alonjest@1.0.0 test /home/milenko/pract/alonjest
> jest __tests__

 FAIL  .history/__tests__/user.test_20201028132815.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

   Details:

    /home/milenko/pract/alonjest/.history/__tests__/user.test_20201028132815.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import mockingoose from 'mockingoose';
```

Package.json

```
  "name": "alonjest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "user.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest __tests__"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^5.10.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.1",
    "mockingoose": "^2.13.2"
  }
}
```

Dir structure

```
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
__tests__
user.mjs
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: You have to explicitly tell Node that your source file is an ES2015 module. You can do that in the package file or by naming your file "something.mjs".

Comment: If you do a google search for that error message you'll find plenty of information.

Comment: @Pointy I changed user.js to uer.mjs.The same!

Comment: [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) — also note that you need a fairly up-to-date version of Node.

Comment: Mine is v14.8.0.